# Imprimir mensagem na pagina após o echo

Tags: php

Ao preencher um formulário em HTML, coloquei para aparecer em PHP na outra página. Porém ao preencher o formulário é chamado a outra página e os valores ficam só na URL e não é mostrado o "echo" na página. Segue abaixo o código que usei em HTML  e PHP

```
<form method="get" action="p1.php"> 
   Valor <input type="number" name="ds"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Envie"/>
</form>

<?php
  $valor = $_GET["ds"];
  echo "O valor inserido é $valor";
?>
```

Comment: É só isso mesmo que tem no seu código ?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo.

Comment: Esta página p1.php é a mesma que você colocou esse código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendo utilizar o método POST

```
HTML - <form method="POST" action="p1.php"> 
                Valor <input type="number" name="ds"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Envie"/>
            </form>

PHP - <?php
        $valor = $_POST["ds"];
        echo "O valor inserido é ".$valor;
        ?>
```

Comment: Não aparece nada ainda. Mesmo usando o método POST.

Comment: se você mandar imprimir somente o texto ele aparece???

Comment: Também não aparece nada.

Comment: como esta mandando imprimir somente o texto???

Comment: Só pelo "echo "frase";"

Comment: verifique se esta editando o arquivo correto, no caso o p1.PHP, veja se ele esta na mesma pasta que o formulário e também verifique o seu interpretador de PHP

Comment: Estão na mesma pasta. Será que é algum erro com minha máquina?

Comment: Verifica o interpretador do PHP, esta usando o xampp ou algo do tipo? veja se eles estão inicializados e o site deve estar na pasta htdocs da instalação.

Comment: Estou usando o Xampp mesmo, está startado o APACHE e MySQL. A pasta está no htdocs.

Comment: por acaso nao tem nenhum css que indique que a cor de texto do body é branca ? :P

Comment: a resposta do Ygor Anjos funciona correctamente. O problema tem que estar com seu servidor. Copiei o codigo que o Ygor colocou aqui e testei, e funcionou perfeito. :/

Comment: Habilite também a exibição de erros no PHP.

Comment: Coloque o trecho de código `error_reporting(E_ALL);` no seu código php, seguindo a ideia do @Marcos Xavier.

Comment: Fiz tudo e nada, o valor vai para a url, porém na página não imprime nada. Vou testar com o EasyPHP.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, o seu código está certo. O que que tens que fazer é certificar que estas a correr a pagina no servidor, tens que poder acessar a sua pagina por exemplo assim `http://localhost/index.php` em vez de `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs//index.php`

Comment: copiei o seu codigo e funcionou sem problemas

Comment: Cara, agora imprimiu na tela o  echo, porém com erro. Aparece assim

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: v in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject5\go.php on line 14
O valor é inserido é

Comment: A linha 14 está com a seguinte observação: "Não acessar Array Superglobal $_GET Diretamente" . A linha 14 é a do get "$valor = $_GET["v"];". O que pode ser?

Comment: Deu certo, eu tinha mudado para ver se dava certo. Era o local de acesso do servidor mesmo. Valeu,cara.

Comment: O problema estava na url que eu buscava o arquivo, mudei para localhost e deu certo. Muito obrigado, galera.

Comment: uma forma coreta de impremir valores de variaveis em php consiste em verificar se a varial exites. Ex: 


if isset( $_GET["v"]){
    echo  $_GET["v"];
}


http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/isset.php

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está correto, deve funcionar perfeitamente.

Algumas causas comuns que podem afetar iniciantes:

- Não ter um interpretador instalado em sua máquina;

Resolver isto é simples. Basta instalar um emulador de servidor, como o WAMP: [Site oficial do Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

- Esquecer de colocar o código PHP dentro do arquivo e organizá-lo em pastas.

No seu caso, basta que o seu `p1.php` esteja com o código PHP, e na mesma pasta que seu `index.php`;

- Problemas com o CSS;

Verifique se o CSS não interfere na sua página.

Recomendo dar um `var_dump` no seu `$valor`. Basta adicionar isso abaixo do seu `echo`: `var_dump($valor)`. Ele irá te retornar o tipo da variável e seu valor.